# flickr API: logout android

Tags: android, browser, flickr

My main concern: Is there any way to logout from flickr in android:

Work done: flickr stores app credantials in sharepreferences. i have delete them. but it users the browser save data to recognise I am logged in or not.
     If i delete the browser's histroy then it ask me for login.

So my need is 
      Any way to logout from flickr 
    or delete the browser's data.(don't work with delete cookies.or cache)
[image]
I have use the flickr code form :https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/

Thanks

Comment: Any Update on this .I am also facing this problem.

Comment: Yes you need to create you webview to load and redirect to your app. For inside webview you can clear its data so that you will be logout.

Comment: Yes ,Actually I already done like that... Anyway thanks..